# Encrypt Cakephp - Decrypt with vb.net and viceversa

Tags: vb.net, cakephp, encryption

I currently have the following *configuration* for **Authentication** component in **CakePHP**

```
public $components = array(     
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authError' => 'Please login to your account',          
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);
```

And my work is integrated with vb.net windows form application. Is there a way or an Authentication class that can be common between both **vb.net** & **CakePHP**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password hashing is an irreversible process. You cannot "decrypt" them.

If you want to use the same hashes for authentication in your vb.net code then use the same hashing algo to hash user provided plain password and then compare the hashes. When using password hasher with sha256, the hash is generated by appending security salt to the plain text string and then the resulting string is sha256 hashed. So do the same in your vb.net code.

Comment: where can I find the salt text?

Comment: `Security.salt` config in `app/Config/core.php`